# Asp.net mvc & Entity Framework : errors when multiple users use to the application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having strange errors on production environment which I don't have on development environment: When testing with 4 users the application is working fine without errors, but when 10 users are using the application at the same time, I have multiple errors such as `connection is already open` or `datareader needs a valid connection.`
I managed to correct this errors by enabling MARS on my connectionstring and by using "using blocks" to dispose my connections objects but I still have other errors such as

```
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.*InnerExceptionSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

or

```
Unable to set field/property Address on entity type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_B22E7C85832E5768701582412113F0C185707EA5275299E638DA68EECEC6CCE5. See InnerException for details.*Inner exceptionSystem.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

and after a few tests,  I have the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on most functions and the users can't use the application and I have to restart IIS so that users can use the application again.

Is there any particular IIS 7 or/and SQL SERVER 2008 R2 configuration to do ?  or code changes ?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is your context lifespan? This looks like multiple thread addressing the same context object.